# Why absolute position in CSS keeps binding to document body instead of enclosing div?

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML/CSS.

The entire page is 1000 pixels by 1000 pixels and is wrapped by a box. For alignment purposes, I'm temporarily placing a solid black border around everything that I will make hidden or invisible later. There is an image on the top left (#Logo), followed by a div box (#Upper_Left) just to the right of the logo.

I want to use absolute positioning to put things up against the top or bottom edge of the #Upper_Left div box. In this case the h1 title goes along the top of the box and some other text ["Search:____________[drop][drop]" - placeholder for a search bar] goes along the bottom-left of the div box. In my HTML/CSS code, the "Search:____________[drop][drop]" text appears at the bottom left of the browser, not the #Upper_Left div box.

How do I make the text position be relative to the div box?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;

                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            * {
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: black;
                border-width: 1px;
            }
            #Entire_Page {
                max-width: 1000px;
                max-height: 1000px;
                min-width: 1000px;
                min-height: 1000px;
            }
            #Logo {
                float: left;
                width:104px;
                height:118px;
            }
            #Upper_Left {
                display: inline;
                float: left;
                max-width: 500px;
                max-height: 118px;
                min-width: 500px;
                min-height: 118px;
            }
            #Title {
                display: inline;
                font-size: 3em;
            }
            #bottom_left {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0px;
                left: 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="Entire_Page">
            <img id="Logo" src="logo.png" alt="logo">
            <div id="Upper_Left">
                <h1 id="Title">Title (Up Top)</h1>
                <div id="bottom_left">
                    Search:____________[drop][drop]
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to specify a wrapper element to be positioned relative, then an absolutely positioned child will position itself relative to its parent. `.parent { position: relative; } .parent div { position: absolute: top 10px; left: 10px; }`

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: So in this case, the wrapper element would be the outer div [the 1000 pixel by 1000 pixel one whose name is Entire_Page?] Or would you define a div in between Entire_Page and the inner div with absolute position set?

Comment: It depends on what you're looking for. If the outer div is taking the same position as the document body, then you need to make style changes to move it away - or create another element and style that to get the positioning you require.

Comment: As @Paulie_D mentioned - absolute positioning is a bad candidate for the default layout of elements. It's normally used for laying out elements in very specific cases.

Comment: Paulie_D - I read that exact thing before I wrote this. I need the search bar to go along the bottom of the box. How would you, as a pro, design this... http://imgur.com/cGJBe37

Comment: In the above imgur link, there is a gap between the right side of the search bar and the left side of the "Upload" dropdown menu. I made the stuff to the left [title, search bar] go in a div box and I wanted the search bar to go along the bottom edge and the <h1> Title to go along the top edge, with the Title and search bar together to have the same height as the logo on the upper left.

Comment: @PaulRedmond - So that's what I'm trying to do. If you know a better way than absolute layout to get the search bar and the title to have the same height as the logo, with the search bar along the bottom edge and the title along the top edge, just say so.

Comment: @Paulie_D - surely after dedicating an entire comment to telling me that there is a much better solution, you must have the ability to provide a way of meeting the requirements in plain CSS2 without using absolute layout.

Comment: @MichaelLafayette For now we can just fix your setup. You could give the divs specific heights to keep them the same.

Comment: Positioning always positions with respect to the last ancestor that was itself positioned (and not just auto-flowed into the page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative;`.

```
 #Upper_Left {
   position: relative;
   display: inline;
   float: left;
   max-width: 500px;
   max-height: 118px;
   min-width: 500px;
   min-height: 118px;
  }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZwNam

Comment: Do you want it positioned at the bottom of `#Upper_Left`?

Comment: Yes. The search box goes along the bottom of the box whose name is Upper_Left. All I needed to know was that "Positioning always positions with respect to the last ancestor that was itself positioned (and not just auto-flowed into the page)" - thank you

Comment: No problem, and that's the important concept that you've learned in CSS which is very valuable.